# Ubuntu 18.10 and 19.04 - Hyphen in Hostname?

Tags: hostname

I have tried setting my hostname to d-myserver1 via editing the /etc/hostname file and via 'sudo hostnamectl set-hostname d-myserver1'. If I run hostnamectl, the hostname is reflected properly. If I release and renew the IP, the correct hostname is reflected in my DHCP server.

The moment I reboot however, the d- is removed and my server reverts to a hostname of simply 'myserver1'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a static hostname definition (in /etc/hosts)? Or perhaps the hostname `myserver1` is being pushed via DHCP?

Comment: The issue was that  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg had  preserve_hostname: false and needed to be changed to  preserve_hostname: true.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg had preserve_hostname: false and needed to be changed to preserve_hostname: true.